# Lazy loading the addthis script? (or lazy loading external js content dependent on already fired events)

Tags: javascript, optimization, widget, dom-events

I want to have the [addthis](http://www.addthis.com) widget available for my users, but I want to lazy load it so that my page loads as quickly as possible. However, after trying it via a script tag and then via my lazy loading method, it appears to only work via the script tag. In the obfuscated code, I see something that looks like it's dependent on the DOMContentLoaded event (at least for Firefox).

Since the DOMContentLoaded event has already fired, the widget doesn't render properly. What to do?

I could just use a script tag (slower)... or could I fire (in a cross browser way) the DOMContentLoaded (or equivalent) event? I have a feeling this may not be possible because I believe that (like jQuery) there are multiple tests of the content ready event, and so multiple simulated events would have to occur.

Nonetheless, this is an interesting problem because I have seen a couple widgets now assume that you are including their stuff via static script tags. It would be nice if they wrote code that was more useful to developers concerned about speed, but until then, is there a work around? And/or are any of my assumptions wrong?

**Edit:** 
Because the 1st answer to the question seemed to miss the point of my problem, I wanted to clarify the situation.

This is about a specific problem. I'm not looking for yet another lazy load script or check if some dependencies are loaded script. **Specifically** this problem deals with

1. external widgets that you do not
   have control over and may or may not
   be obfuscated
2. delaying the load of the 
   external widgets until they
   are needed or at least, til
   substantially after everything else
   has been loaded including other deferred elements
3. b/c of the how
   the widget was written, precludes
   existing, typical lazy loading
   paradigms

While it's esoteric, I have seen it happen with a couple widgets - where the widget developers assume that you're just willing to throw in another script tag at the bottom of the page. I'm looking to save those 500-1000 ms** though as numerous studies by Yahoo, Google, and Amazon show it to be important to your user's experience.

**My testing with hammerhead and personal experience indicates that this will be my savings in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code solves the problem and saves the loading time that I was looking for.

After reading this [post](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2008/12/04/domcontentloaded-inconsistencies/) about how most current js libraries implement tests for a dom loaded event. I spent some time with the obfuscated code, and I was able to determine that addthis uses a combination of the mentioned doscroll method, timers, and the DOMContentLoaded event for various browsers. Since only those browsers dependent on the DOMContentloaded event would need the following code anyway:

```
if( document.createEvent ) {
 var evt = document.createEvent("MutationEvents"); 
 evt.initMutationEvent("DOMContentLoaded", true, true, document, "", "", "", 0); 
 document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

and the rest depend on timers testing for existence of certain properties, I only had to accommodate this one case to be able to lazy load this external JS content rather than using the static script tags, thus saving the time that I was hoping for. :)

Answer (score 12):

The simplest solution is to set parameter **domready** to 1 when embedding addthis script into your page. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=addthis&domready=1">
</script>
```

I have tested it on IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, and all worked fine. More information on addthis configuration parameters is available [here](http://www.addthis.com/help/menu-api).

Comment: This blog post was super-helpful http://t.co/6uk9sHU0. Essentially after you load your content via ajax you load the addthis script via $.getScript then call addthis.init() once the script has finished loading.

Comment: right now there is also ``async`` option that makes page load even faster. http://www.addthis.com/help/optimizing-addthis

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If the goal is simply to have your other contetn load first, try putting the `<script>` tags near the bottom of your page. It will still be able to catch the DOMContentLoaded and the content that comes before will be loaded before the script.

Original:

in addition to loading on DOMContentLoaded, you could have it load if a certain var is set true. e.g.

```
var isDOMContentLoaded = false;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() { isDOMContentLoaded = true; }, false);
```

then add to the other script file

```
if (isDOMContentLoaded) loadThisScript();
```

Edit in response to comments:

Load the script, and run the function that the DOMContentLoaded listener fires. (*read* the script if you're not sure what function is being called ).

e.g.

```
var timerID;
var iteration=0;

function checkAndLoad() {
    if (typeof loadThisScript != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(timerID);
        loadThisScript();
    }
    iteration++;
    if (iteration > 59) clearInterval(timerID);
}

var extScript = document.createElement("script");
extScript.setAttribute("src",scriptSrcHere);
document.head.appendChild(extScript);

timerID = setInterval(checkAndLoad,1000);
```

The above will try once a second for 60 seconds to check if the function you need is available, and, if so, run it

Comment: It's an external js widget. I have no control over the content.

Comment: There are a couple sections that refer to the DOMContentLoaded event, which call anonymous functions & seem to be in closures with hidden state. This is obfuscated code, so although I'm trying to figure out what exactly they're doing on the DOMContentLoaded event, it may not be that easy. I'm considering a different approach - trying to figure out what events it's looking for and firing those, and I'm wondering if there might be a generalized solution - some code to fire a DOMContentLoaded event after the "real" one by the browser has already fired or some other way to trigger it.

Comment: take the anonymous functions out and give them a name in your script. var loadFunction = function() { /* whatever*/ }
then call those functions from the checkAndLoad()

Comment: How would I take the anonymous functions out? I don't have control over the external js.

Comment: there is not, to my knowledge, any way to fire DOMContentLoaded after the page has already fired it once. There is something similar for jquery for simulating mouse and keyboard events, but nothing that I know of for DOMcontentLoaded

Comment: download the js and copy/paste

Comment: But it has state within that function that I couldn't simply cut & paste that section. I would need to understand what's state of the various variable at the time that it's being called - so I have to spend more time dissecting obfuscated code. I may ultimately have to do this if there is no work around, but I'm hoping another approach might be more fruitful.

Comment: you might consider this firefox add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345 It should help you analyze what the script is doing

Comment: thanks for link to the add-on. i look forward to testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

AddThis has a section on [how to load their tools asynchronously](https://www.addthis.com/academy/using-addthis-asynchronously/).

Current 'best' solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=[YOUR PROFILE ID]" async="async"></script>
```